# Adonis : delete width joins

Tags: javascript, mysql, api, sql-delete, adonis.js

When i try to execute the query below, i’ve got the following error :

> Unknown field ‘Attributes.list_id’ in where clause

(I’m not using await because I execute this query in another async function).

```
const result = Database
  .select('line', 'value')
  .from(table)
  .where('line', params.linePosition)
  .innerJoin('attributes', 'attributes.id', table + '.attribute_id')
  .where('attributes.list_id', params.listId)
  .delete()
```

When I remove the deletion part, it works.

Is there an existing method in adonis to do this kind of tricks ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you show your error ?

Comment: @AmitKadivar

**Here is the error**


`delete from `text_values` where `line` = '5' and `attributes`.`list_id` = '1' - ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Champ 'attributes.list_id' inconnu dans where clause"}`

Comment: show your migration ?